# Access denied, unable to find the controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, acl

I'm getting access denied when I want to change the order status in adminpanel. The url of the page is .../index.php/admin/advancedorderstatus_grid/mass/action/change_orde_status. I tried to find the controller and add the isAllowed function, but can not find it. Is there any simple way to locate its controller?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you talk about an outdated version of the XTENTO Advanced Order Status extension, there is [an entry in their Wiki](http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Magento_Extensions:Advanced_Order_Status#SUPEE-6285_Patch) that includes a patch.